# What are Spark RDD graph, lineage graph, DAG of Spark tasks? what are their relations

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, directed-acyclic-graphs

When we talk about RDD graphs, does it mean lineage graph or DAG (direct acyclic graph) or both? and when is the lineage graph generated? is it generated before the DAG of Spark tasks?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An RDD can depend on zero or more other RDDs. For example when you say `x = y.map(...)`, `x` will depend on `y`. These dependency relationships can be thought of as a graph.

You can call this graph a *lineage* graph, as it represents the derivation of each RDD. It is also necessarily a *DAG*, since a loop is impossible to be present in it.

Narrow dependencies, where a shuffle is not required (think `map` and `filter`) can be collapsed into a single *stage*. Stages are a unit of execution, and they are generated by the [`DAGScheduler`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.4.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/DAGScheduler.scala) from the graph of RDD dependencies. Stages also depend on each other. The `DAGScheduler` builds and uses this dependency graph (which is also necessarily a DAG) to schedule the stages.

Comment: Daniel Darabos : Suppose if Leneage graph could be subitted to DAGScheduler? Coudn't DAGScheduler schedule stages based on the info provided by Leneage Graph? as Leneage graph also defines relationships/dependencies between RDDs!
Thnx

Comment: This is from 5 years ago, but I think that's exactly how it works.